# Dnsmasq Configuration to a Single IP

Tags: linux, server, dnsmasq

I am using DNSMasq as a service on my network.  The machine that has DNSMasq installed has two network cards.  (the IP addresses are 192.168.1.5 and 192.168.1.6).

The issue I have run into is that I have a pod container running PiHole on the the same machine.  When I reboot, PiHole fails to start because DNSMasq is using the ports required.  PiHole is set to specifically use 192.168.1.6 (ports 80, 443, 52, 67).  When I run `# lsof - :67`, I see that DNSMasq is listening to port 67 on both IP addresses when I have it specifically set to listen to only 192.168.1.5.

Is there another way to restrict DNSMasq to a single IP address (not loopback or localhost) and make it ignore a specific IP address (in this case, 192.168.1.6 is not touched by DNSMasq)?

Here is my `/etc/dnsmasq.d/default.conf`

```
no-resolv
no-poll
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.8.8
listen-address=192.168.1.5
interface=eno2
bind-interfaces
```

Comment: Are both your interfaces in the same subnet?

Comment: Yes.  Both devices are on the same subnet.